# Phonegap oauth on client

Tags: cordova, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am working on a phonegap app and something which is becoming a real issue is oauth authentication on the client.

The only well documented example of doing this is Libby's tutorial on the topic

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1

... the only thing that is stopping me from using this is the fact my consumerKey + Secret would be completely visible in the Javascript.

Surely this is a bad thing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520626/how-it-is-possible-to-not-expose-you-secret-key-with-a-javascript-oauth-library